# How to implement __() function in my theme's php file?

Tags: php, functions, translation

I am translating a site with Polylang that was created by someone else using a custom theme. Some strings couldn't be found by Polylang, so I need to manually register them for Polylang to see.

Now, some of the strings were pretty easy to translate using `__()`:

```
    $args = shortcode_atts([
    'link'      => 'service',
    'text'      => __('Get the code now!'),
    'title'     => __('Code'),
    'id'        => '',
    'class'     => 'width300',
], $args, '' );
```

But I don't know how to translate strings in these scenarios:

```
        $popup = do_shortcode('[popup id="110" link="vacancy" class="" title="Code" text="Get the code now!!" ]');
```

or here words Details, Close

```
        $script = ' 
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                btn = $(\'.add_vakan_info\'),
                popup = $(\'.add_popup\');

                btn.click(function(){
                    var block_info  = $(this).closest(\'.vacancy\').find(\'.content\');
                    if(block_info.hasClass(\'active\')){
                        block_info.removeClass(\'active\');
                        $(this).html(\'Details <i class="las la-angle-down"></i>\');
                    }else{
                        block_info.addClass(\'active\');
                        $(this).html(\'Close <i class="las la-angle-up"></i>\');
                    }
                })
                popup.click(function(){
                    var text = $(this).closest(\'.vacancy\').find(\'.title\').text(),
                        form = $(\'.vacancy_name\');
                    form.val(text);
                })
                FileInput();
            })
        </script>';
```

or

```
    else:
    $html = '<h4>No vacancy </h4>';
```

or

```
                <div class="content col">
                <div class="sp-20"></div>
                <h4>Description</h4>
                '.$description.'

                <div class="sp-20"></div>
                <h4>Requirements</h4>
                '.$requirements.'

                <div class="sp-20"></div>
                <h4>Conditions</h4>
                '.$conditions.'
```

Comment: `__` is not a polylang function, it's a WordPress core function, the root problem here appears to be that you don't know how to insert values into strings in PHP

Comment: Turrible name for these functions, in my opinion.  WP docs are always a good place to start:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/